# Is there an alternative to GetCalendarByID for personal calendars?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google sheet with all the events a new hire has added to their calendar. I created a script, however, I realized after that for personal calendars, it does not generate a calendarID (it only shows an email address). I can't figure out how to update my script so when I run it, it will add these events when logged into a new hire's Google calendar (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getownedcalendarsbynamename).

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("A8:D"+lr+"").getValues();

  for (i=0; x < range.length; i++) {
      var cells = range[i];
      var summary = cells[0];
      var startTime = cells[1];
      var endTime = cells[2];
      var description = cells[3];

      var options = {
        'description': description,
      }
      eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### For primary calendars the calendarID is exactly the same like the user email

However, you cannot simply insert events into a calendar that is not yours.

There are two things you can do instead:

1. Insert an event into your / the companies shared calendar to which you have editor rights and invite the hire to the event as a guest - like in [this sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createalldayeventseriestitle,-startdate,-recurrence,-options):

```
var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries('No Meetings',
    new Date('January 2, 2013 03:00:00 PM EST'),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
        .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY)
        .until(new Date('January 1, 2014')),
    {guests: 'everyone@example.com'});
```

2. User a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) with [Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) that allows you to impersonate the user and act on his behalf - that is insert an event into his calendar as if you were him.